# Avoid recursive call Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this problem and I need to give a solution to avoid the recursive call `f(T,S)` in both clauses:

```
f([],0).
f([H|T],S):-
    f(T,S1),
    S1>=2,
    !,
    S=S1+H.
f([_|T],S):-
    f(T,S1),
    S=S1+1.
```

I don't understand what this does...
And I really have no idea how I could avoid that recursive call.
Please help me with a solution

Comment: Wasn't the task to avoid **non-tail** recursive call? Above code is calculating sum of the elements in the list, there is no easy way (I don't know any) to do it without recursion.

Comment: That predicate doesn't compute a sum. It will actually, for a list like `[1,2,3,4]`, result in `S = 0+1+1+2+1`. So it needs some work as-is. One issue is that, in prolog, `=/2` is *not* an arithmetic assignment statement. To assign an arithmetic expression, use `is/2`.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about `is/2`. Still, I don't think it's possible to do that without recursion.

Comment: @Świstak35 actually, I think the OP's use of `=` is OK in this case. I didn't notice the Turbo Prolog tag. Turbo Prolog allows `=` to be used as `is` (not sure why, but it does). I agree: recursion is the only simple way to do it, but there is a choice between tail recursive and non-tail recursive as you indicated.

Comment: @Świstak35 after puzzling through the predicate, I realized that it doesn't computer the sum of a list (as it first appears), but adds the value of a list's head to the length of its body. Strange, that.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I replaced propositions of the form `L = M + N` with `L is M + N`, since I'm not using Turbo Prolog, but I'd guess everything else will be the same.*

Your `f/2` predicate is a strange one. The third clause just counts the length of a list but
the second relates S1 to the tail of the list, and adds the value determined for S1 to the value of the head **if** S1 > 1. In other words, `f/2` adds the head to the length of the tail if the tail is > 1, or else it just returns the length of the list (i.e., 1 or 2); e.g.,

```
?- f([1], X).
X = 1.

?- f([2], X).
X = 1.

?- f([2,1], X).
X = 2.

?- f([3,1], X).
X = 2.

?- f([3,1,1], X).
X = 5.

?- f([2,1,1], X).
X = 4.
```

The second and third clauses of `f/2` describe quite different relations. The second predicate relates the integer value of a list's head to the length of the list's body, *provided a certain condition holds*. The third predicate simply relates an integer to a list, such that the value of the integer is the same as the number of elements in a list. I.e., it describes the length of a list. Prolog excels at declarative programming and at helping us understand problems by forcing/enabling us to write clear and concise descriptions of relationships. The second and third clauses of `f/2` describe different relations, so we can (and should) use two different predicates. As you'll see, this will allow us to remove the recursive call from the the predicate `f/2`, since the recursion is only necessary for determining the length relationship (but we still have recursion in operation, it's just not a recursive call to `f/2`). Here's one possible solution (it simply uses the built-in `length/2`, but you can replace this with your own predicate if you're not allowed to use built-ins):

```
f([], 0).
f([H|T],S):-
    length(T, Len),    % Len is the length of T
    ( Len > 1          % if Len is greater than 1
    ->
        S is Len + H   % then the value of S is Len plus the value of H
    ;
        S is Len + 1   % otherwise, S is Len + 1 ( the addition is to make up for the missing H)
    ).
```

You could actually refractor this further to eliminate the conditional:

```
head_plus_length_of_tail([E1, E2 | Es], N) :-
    length([E2|Es], Len),
    N is E1 + Len.

g(List, N) :-
    head_plus_length_of_tail(List, N), !.
g(List, N) :-
    length(List, N).
```

head_plus_length_of_tail/2 only succeeds if there are three or more elements in a list (which takes care of the conditional that checks if the length of the list's body is > 1. If that succeeds, we cut, so it won't backtrack to give us the length of the list as well. Otherwise we just get the length of the list.